# no such module SDImageView

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, sdwebimage

This error appears after one of "pod update" calls.

I've already tried:

- Completely remove all CocoaPods-related files and dirs
- Restart XCode

I'm sure that I'm opening Workspace instead of project (there's no errors for SwiftyJson).

Pods framework is added to "Link with":

[image]

Error message:

[image]

Files listing:

```
$ ls Pods/SDWebImage/
LICENSE     README.md   SDWebImage
```

XCode version is 7.3.1, OS X 10.11.

Comment: if by `remove all CocoaPods-related files and dirs`, I hope you mean you removed the pod from your Podfile and ran `pod install`. Any other means of removing a pod is a bad idea.

Comment: @rigdonmr I've removed Pods dir and Podfile, then ran pod init and re-created Podfile.

Comment: In the future just removing the pod from the Podfile and running pod install is much cleaner/safer for your project. When you have CocoaPods it just kinda creates this dependency hell all over your project and settings. Leave the removing process to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the problem was solved by calling

> pod deintegrate

removing xcworkspace and reinstalling pods.